# Prolog - Split a list in two halves, reversing the first half

Tags: list, split, prolog, reverse

I am asked to take a list of letters into two lists that are either equal in size (even sized original list I guess) or one is larger than the other by one element (odd sized list), and reverse the first one while I'm at it.

Query and output example:

```erlang
?- dividelist2([a,b,c,d,e,f], L1,L2).
L1 = [c,b,a]
L2 = [d,e,f]

?- dividelist2([a,b,c,d,e], L1,L2).
L1 = [c,b,a]
L2 = [d,e]
% OR
L1 = [b,a]
L2 = [c,d,e]
```

I've reached this solution, but I have a feeling something is wrong with it. Please let me know if I'm missing something... How do I get the last output? (two options for output, I mean)

```erlang
dividelist2(L, X, B) :-
  (  append(A, B, L),
     length(A, O),
     length(B, N),
     (  (O-1) =:= N
     ;  (O+1) =:= N
     ;  O     =:= N
     ),
     !
  ), reverse(A, X).

reverse(List, Rev) :-
        reverse(List, Rev, []).

reverse([], L, L).
reverse([H|T], L, SoFar) :-
        reverse(T, L, [H|SoFar]).
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your solution is correct. it's just a bit inefficient. try running it with lists of length 1000 and 10000, and measure the number of inferences it takes to complete (using `time/1`). [is it linear? is it quadratic?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) a [linear solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57317659/prolog-split-a-list-in-two-halves-reversing-the-first-half#comment101136827_57317913) exists.

Comment: Thanks. do you know how I can do it with Difference lists?

Comment: you don't need list differences here since you *reverse* the first half, and get the second half for free. :)

Comment: I've been asked now to re-make the same question but with difference lists:(
I've tried remaking the "Append" to difference lists's new append method, but it doesn't work.

Comment: this would make sense only if you were creating the first half in its original order, non-reversed. if that's the case, you can ask a new question about it. which of the two results is to be built as DL? or is it both? specify all the details in your new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track:

```
splitflip(In, Out1, Out2) :-
    length(In, L), % length of the list
    FL is L//2, % integer division, so half the length, Out1 will be 1 shorter than Out2 if L is odd
    ( \+ (FL*2 =:= L), % is odd
      FLP is FL + 1 % odd case, choicepoint left
    ; FLP = FL % odd and even case, no choicepoint left
    ), % the one place we need a choicepoint for the odd length case of an odd input, note order prunes choicepoint for even case
    length(FirstHalf, FLP), % generate an list of vars to the right length
    append(FirstHalf, Out2, In), % unify with the first half and generate second half of correct length
    reverse(FirstHalf, Out1). % do the reverse
```

Just need to reorder things a bit and use integer division.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how re-ordering changes things?

Comment: You do the append before the length checks, which is a standard generate and test strategy. I constrain the solution by defining then lengths before the append. If you run a trace you'll see constraining is far more efficient than generate and test, in this case I call append only once, yours would call it length/2 times. This also meant there was no need to consider the length of the second half of the list, it had to be correct.

Comment: @PaulBrown yes, but, your code fails to produce the two solutions in case the length was odd, as the Q seems to require. :)

Comment: @WillNess It does now! Still det for even, and leaves no choicepoint for odd after the two solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @WillNess, I have a full solution here using the tortoise/hare trick. The idea behind that trick is that you are traversing the list simultaneously, with the tortoise going element by element and the hare going by two elements at a time. When the hare list is empty, you know you're at the middle of the list. This inlines a common accumulator pattern for reversing a list in one pass, which is how we produce the first half of the result. The second half of the result is just the remainder of the list--which is to say, the tortoise list.

```
divide(List, Left, Right) :-
    reverse(List, List, [], Left, Right).

% reverse(Tortoise, Hare, ReverseAccumulator, RevFirstHalf, SecondHalf)
reverse(Right, [], Left, Left, Right).
reverse([X|Xs], [_,_|Rem], Acc, Left, Right) :-
    reverse(Xs, Rem, [X|Acc], Left, Right).
```

As you can see, the hare is just here to be traversed two-at-a-time until it becomes empty, which triggers our base case. This works fine for even-length lists.

For odd-length lists we must handle them by noticing that the hare is a single-item list. Then we need to produce two more solutions, so we have two clauses for the single-item list case: one that places the next tortoise item into the first half list, one that places it into the second half:

```
reverse([X|Xs], [_], Acc, Left, Right) :-
    reverse([X|Xs], [], Acc, Left, Right).
reverse([X|Xs], [_], Acc, Left, Right) :-
    reverse(Xs, [], [X|Acc], Left, Right).
```

This produces the results you want. It's a little hard to understand what is going on at first, but it is more efficient than the accepted answer, probably because it doesn't allocate as much. For comparison, I ran both on a list of 5 million entries; this version ran somewhat faster:

```
?- length(L, 5000000), time(splitflip(L, Left, Right)).
% 5,000,014 inferences, 0.806 CPU in 0.806 seconds (100% CPU, 6200835 Lips)
L = [_58, _64, _70, _76, _82, _88, _94, _100, _106|...],
Left = [_15000052, _15000046, _15000040, _15000034, _15000028, _15000022, _15000016, _15000010, _15000004|...],
Right = [_15000058, _15000064, _15000070, _15000076, _15000082, _15000088, _15000094, _15000100, _15000106|...].

?- length(L, 5000000), time(divide(L, Left, Right)).
% 2,500,001 inferences, 0.567 CPU in 0.568 seconds (100% CPU, 4405613 Lips)
L = [_850, _856, _862, _868, _874, _880, _886, _892, _898|...],
Left = [_15000844, _15000838, _15000832, _15000826, _15000820, _15000814, _15000808, _15000802, _15000796|...],
Right = [_15000850, _15000856, _15000862, _15000868, _15000874, _15000880, _15000886, _15000892, _15000898|...] .
```

**Edit**: Original answer follows.

This is only a partial solution. I'm missing something obvious about how to convert this to the full solution, and I don't have a lot of time at the moment to finish it, but I thought it might be useful to share anyway. And probably another [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog) answerer will see immediately where the problem is.

My plan here is basically to be reversing the list and tracking the index I'm at from the start on the way into the recursive call, and be tracking the index I'm at from the *end* on the way *out* of the recursive call. With that in-hand, if the indexes match, we take the reversed prefix and the suffix and that is the result. We can define "match" as the indexes are within 1 of each other, with a separate predicate.

```
reverse(_, [], 0, Z, Z).
reverse(I, [X|Xs], J1, Z, Acc) :-
    succ(I, I1),
    reverse(I1, Xs, J, Z, [X|Acc]),
    succ(J, J1).
```

The combination of pieces that I think we need are visible in this code when viewed in the `trace.` output:

```
[trace]  ?- reverse(0, [a,b,c,d], _, R, []).
   Call: (8) reverse(0, [a, b, c, d], _694, _696, []) ? creep
   Call: (9) succ(0, _964) ? creep
   Exit: (9) succ(0, 1) ? creep
   Call: (9) reverse(1, [b, c, d], _972, _696, [a]) ? creep
   Call: (10) succ(1, _970) ? creep
   Exit: (10) succ(1, 2) ? creep
   Call: (10) reverse(2, [c, d], _978, _696, [b, a]) ? creep
   Call: (11) succ(2, _976) ? creep
   Exit: (11) succ(2, 3) ? creep
   Call: (11) reverse(3, [d], _984, _696, [c, b, a]) ? creep
   Call: (12) succ(3, _982) ? creep
   Exit: (12) succ(3, 4) ? creep
   Call: (12) reverse(4, [], _990, _696, [d, c, b, a]) ? creep
   Exit: (12) reverse(4, [], 0, [d, c, b, a], [d, c, b, a]) ? creep
   Call: (12) succ(0, _988) ? creep
   Exit: (12) succ(0, 1) ? creep
   Exit: (11) reverse(3, [d], 1, [d, c, b, a], [c, b, a]) ? creep
   Call: (11) succ(1, _988) ? creep
   Exit: (11) succ(1, 2) ? creep
   Exit: (10) reverse(2, [c, d], 2, [d, c, b, a], [b, a]) ? creep
   Call: (10) succ(2, _988) ? creep
   Exit: (10) succ(2, 3) ? creep
   Exit: (9) reverse(1, [b, c, d], 3, [d, c, b, a], [a]) ? creep
   Call: (9) succ(3, _694) ? creep
   Exit: (9) succ(3, 4) ? creep
   Exit: (8) reverse(0, [a, b, c, d], 4, [d, c, b, a], []) ? creep
R = [d, c, b, a] .
```

Note particularly this line:

```
   Exit: (10) reverse(2, [c, d], 2, [d, c, b, a], [b, a]) ? creep
```

As you can see, at this moment we have I = J = 2, and we have a list `[b,a]` and a list `[c,d]`. This gives me hope that this is close, but for whatever reason I'm not seeing the bridge to the complete solution. Maybe you will!

Comment: we don't need to track anything on the way back as we don't need to go *back* in the first place. :) the standard *turtle-and-hare* trick applies here -- we go along the list maintaining two pointers into it. one skips ahead by one position at a time, the other - by two. yet another argument collects the first half in reverse while we go forth. when the faster "walker" hits the list's end, ... you know the rest! :) (also can be tweaked to produce the *several* outcomes, as the Q describes, so there's no need for *any* counting here)

Comment: @WillNess I've added the solution :)

Comment: yep, takes half the steps.