# Split a list in two halves, reversing the first half using difference lists

Tags: prolog, difference-lists

I need to do an exercise similar to this:
[Prolog - Split a list in two halves, reversing the first half](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57317659/prolog-split-a-list-in-two-halves-reversing-the-first-half).

I am asked to take a list of letters into two lists that are either equal in size (even sized original list I guess) or one is larger than the other by one element (odd sized list), and reverse the first one while I'm at it, but using only difference lists.

These are the required query and output

```
?-dividelist2([a,b,c,d,e,f | T] - T, L1-[], L2-[]).
L1 = [c,b,a]
L2 = [d,e,f]

?-dividelist2([a,b,c,d,e | T] - T, L1-[], L2-[]).
L1 = [c,b,a]
L2 = [d,e]
% OR
L1 = [b,a]
L2 = [c,d,e]
```

This is my code using the previous example but modified, I don't know how to properly compare the two lists 
"deduct" them from the input and produce `[d,e,f]`?

```
dividelist2(In -[], L1-[], L2-[]) :-
     length_dl(In - [],L), % length of the list
     FL is L//2, % integer division, so half the length, Out1 will be 1 shorter than Out2 if L is odd
    ( \+ (FL*2 =:= L), % is odd
      FLP is FL + 1 % odd case
    ; FLP = FL % odd and even case
    ), 
    take(In,FLP,FirstHalf),
    conc([FirstHalf| L2]-l2,L2-[],In-[]),
    reverse1(FirstHalf-[], L1-[]). % do the reverse

reverse1(A- Z,L - L):-
  A == Z , !. 
reverse1([X|Xs] - Z,L - T):-
  reverse1(Xs - Z, L - [X|T]).

length_dl(L- L,0):-!.
length_dl([X|T] - L,N):-
    length_dl(T- L,N1),
    N is N1 + 1 .
take(Src,N,L) :- findall(E, (nth1(I,Src,E), I =< N), L).
conc(L1-T1,T1-T2,L1-T2).
```

This is the current trace:

```
Call:dividelist2([a, b, c, d, e, f|_22100]-_22100, _22116-[], _22112-[])
 Call:length_dl([a, b, c, d, e, f]-[], _22514)
 Call:length_dl([b, c, d, e, f]-[], _22520)
 Call:length_dl([c, d, e, f]-[], _22526)
 Call:length_dl([d, e, f]-[], _22532)
 Call:length_dl([e, f]-[], _22538)
 Call:length_dl([f]-[], _22544)
 Call:length_dl([]-[], _22550)
 Exit:length_dl([]-[], 0)
 Call:_22554 is 0+1
 Exit:1 is 0+1
 Exit:length_dl([f]-[], 1)
 Call:_22560 is 1+1
 Exit:2 is 1+1
 Exit:length_dl([e, f]-[], 2)
 Call:_22566 is 2+1
 Exit:3 is 2+1
 Exit:length_dl([d, e, f]-[], 3)
 Call:_22572 is 3+1
 Exit:4 is 3+1
 Exit:length_dl([c, d, e, f]-[], 4)
 Call:_22578 is 4+1
 Exit:5 is 4+1
 Exit:length_dl([b, c, d, e, f]-[], 5)
 Call:_22584 is 5+1
 Exit:6 is 5+1
 Exit:length_dl([a, b, c, d, e, f]-[], 6)
 Call:_22590 is 6//2
 Exit:3 is 6//2
 Call:3*2=:=6
 Exit:3*2=:=6
 Call:_22590=3
 Exit:3=3
 Call:take([a, b, c, d, e, f], 3, _22594)
 Call:'$bags' : findall(_22518, (nth1(_22514, [a, b, c, d, e, f], _22518),_22514=<3), _22614)
 Exit:'$bags' : findall(_22518, '251db9a2-f596-4daa-adae-38a38a13842c' : (nth1(_22514, [a, b, c, d, e, f], _22518),_22514=<3), [a, b, c])
 Exit:take([a, b, c, d, e, f], 3, [a, b, c])
 Call:conc([[a, b, c]|_22112]-l2, _22112-[], [a, b, c, d, e, f]-[])
 Fail:conc([[a, b, c]|_22112]-l2, _22112-[], [a, b, c, d, e, f]-[])
 Fail:dividelist2([a, b, c, d, e, f|_22100]-_22100, _22116-[], _22112-[])
false
```

thanks

Comment: I can't give a full answer today, but an input difference list gives you easy access to the head and last of the list. You could use this to recurse taking elements off the front and back and use these to build 2 regular lists (or difference lists but the hole is not required). The Craft of Prolog queue implementation has the syntax, you can trace to find the 2 base cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but testing and debugging suggestions that doesn't fit the comment length limit. The suggestions use Logtalk, which you can run with most Prolog systems.

From your question, the `dividelist2/3` predicate needs to satisfy a couple of *properties*, one of them describing the lengths of the resulting lists. We can express this property easily using a predicate, `p/1`:

```
p(DL) :-
    difflist::length(DL, N),
    dividelist2(DL, DL1, DL2),
    difflist::length(DL1, N1),
    difflist::length(DL2, N2),
    N is N1 + N2,
    abs(N1 - N2) =< 1.
```

Here I'm using Logtalk's `difflist` library object to compute the length of the difference lists. Given this predicate, we can now perform some *property-testing* of your `dividelist2/3` predicate.

Using Logtalk `lgtunit` tool implementation of property-testing, we get:

```
?- lgtunit::quick_check(p(+difference_list(integer))).
*     quick check test failure (at test 1 after 0 shrinks):
*       p(A-A)
false.
```

I.e. your code fails for the trivial case of an empty difference list. In the query, we use the `difference_list(integer)` type simply to simplify the generated counter-examples.

Let's try to fix the failure by adding the following clause to your code:

```
dividelist2(A-A, B-B, C-C).
```

Re-trying our test query, we now get:

```
?- lgtunit::quick_check(p(+difference_list(integer))).
*     quick check test failure (at test 2 after 0 shrinks):
*       p([0|A]-A)
false.
```

I.e. the `dividelist2/3` predicate fails for a difference list with a single element. You can now use the difference list in the generated counter-example as a starting point for debugging:

```
?- dividelist2([0|A]-A, L1, L2).
A = [0|A],
L1 = _2540-_2540,
L2 = _2546-_2546 ;
false.
```

You can also use property-testing with your auxiliary predicates. Take the `length_dl/2` predicate. We can compare it with another implementation of a predicate that computes the length of a difference list, e.g. the one in the Logtalk library, by defining another property:

```
q(DL) :-
    difflist::length(DL, N),
    length_dl(DL, N).
```

Testing it we get:

```
?- lgtunit::quick_check(q(+difference_list(integer))).
*     quick check test failure (at test 3 after 0 shrinks):
*       q([-113,446,892|A]-A)
false.
```

Effectively, using the counter.example, we get:

```
?- length_dl([-113,446,892|A]-A, N).
A = [-113, 446, 892|A],
N = 0.
```

Hope that this insight helps in fixing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my idea can work, but seems somewhat inelegant. We'll begin with a handy utility that'll turn a list into a difference list:

```
list_dl([], W-W).
list_dl([H|T1], [H|T2]-W) :-
    list_dl(T1, T2-W).
```

Now we want a predicate to take the first and last element from the difference list. The case where there's only one element left will need to be handled differently, so we'll make that one unique.

```
head_last(Head, Head, DL-Hole, one) :-
    once(append([Head|_], [Last, Hole], DL)),
    var(Last), !.
head_last(Head, Last, DL-Hole, New) :-
    once(append([Head|Mid], [Last, Hole], DL)),
    list_dl(Mid, New).
```

Now we can create our recursive split and reverse predicate, which has 3 base cases:

```
splitrev(W-W, [], []) :- var(W), !. % Empty base case.
splitrev(DL, [V|[]], []) :- head_last(V, V, DL, one).
splitrev(DL, [], [V|[]]) :- head_last(V, V, DL, one).
splitrev(DL, [Head|Front], [Last|Back]) :-
    head_last(Head, Last, DL, Rest),
    splitrev(Rest, Front, Back).
```

Unfortunately it's much easier to add an element to the back of a difference list than it is to get an element from the back, plus getting that element closed the hole in the list. Therefore I think a different strategy would be better.